# Shopware 6 API Create a Product with Variants

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api

I created my products with the API and all is ok. But we have some products with variants. These looking good in the backend, but in the frontend shopware doesn't display the product. Where is my error in the payload?

Thank you for helping me!

Here is my code:

```json
{ 
    "write-product": 
    { 
        "entity": "product", 
        "action": "upsert",  
        "payload": [ 
            {
                "id": "17cf3bac8966cc4de52aa557f59e5fd3",
                "active": true,
                "deliveryTimeId": "1e04777cb17d4396b424129b2d8e3a79",
                "description": "Produktbeschreibung",
                "ean": null,
                "featureSetId": null,
                "manufacturerId": null,
                "manufacturerNumber": null,
                "minPurchase": 1,
                "name": "Produktname",
                "productNumber": "Nummer",
                "releaseDate": "2022-09-28T14:12:18.03",
                "stock": 999999,
                "taxId": "2842fd17d5a7424795853e7fe7072448",
                "price":[
                    {
                        "currencyId": "b7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca",
                        "net": 13.77,
                        "gross": 16.39,
                        "linked": false
                    }
                ],
                "categories":[
                    { 
                        "id":"648875017ed54637a41c8c1f972c239f",
                        "name":"Kategoriename"
                    }
                ],
                "configuratorSettings": [
                    { 
                        "productId": "17cf3bac8966cc4de52aa557f59e5fd3",
                        "optionId": "2ab9df7d2dd94ad38eb53cf7dcf16e56" 
                    },
                    { 
                        "productId": "17cf3bac8966cc4de52aa557f59e5fd3",
                        "optionId": "0fcf784970ea448bac1f7db542df9b86" 
                    },
                    { 
                        "productId": "17cf3bac8966cc4de52aa557f59e5fd3",
                        "optionId": "0014aa7dc0b644b78cd4b39193f580b4" 
                    }
                ],
                "properties": [
                    { 
                        "groupId":"ca74efd59b5545f2b4e4f532c217b2ce",
                        "name": "1,0 m" 
                    },
                    { 
                        "groupId":"fa7f63d697d44684a5bb74ba5a73d3c7",
                        "name": "2,0 mm" 
                    },
                    { 
                        "groupId":"a431bc98fe0149c3bf3ececf629e9740",
                        "name": "Material" 
                    }
                ],
                "visibilities": [
                    {
                        "id": "17cf3bac8966cc4de52aa557f59e5fd3",
                        "salesChannelId": "840a0403b56240b6a11502af1d46521e",
                        "visibility": 30
                    }
                ],
                "coverId": "0f9ab99638bd0ea5e907234bf425819e", 
                "cover": 
                { 
                    "mediaId": "0f9ab99638bd0ea5e907234bf425819e" 
                }, 
                "media": [
                    { 
                        "media": 
                        { 
                            "id": "0f9ab99638bd0ea5e907234bf425819e", 
                            "position": 0, 
                            "mediaFolderId": "d8f460870e454c0bbca540614ca30029",
                            "alt": "Bildname", 
                            "description": "Bildbeschreibung", 
                            "title": "Bildtitel" 
                        } 
                    }
                ],
                "children": [ 
                    {
                        "id": "25c8876fb7577cad78df7539737d25ce",
                        "active": true,
                        "deliveryTimeId": "1e04777cb17d4396b424129b2d8e3a79",
                        "description": "Beschreibung Kindelement",
                        "ean": null,
                        "featureSetId": null,
                        "manufacturerId": null,
                        "manufacturerNumber": null,
                        "minPurchase": 1,
                        "name": "Name Kindelement",
                        "productNumber": "Nummer Kindelement",
                        "releaseDate": "2022-09-16T14:14:31.41",
                        "stock": 999999,
                        "taxId": "2842fd17d5a7424795853e7fe7072448",
                        "price":[
                            {
                                "currencyId": "b7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca",
                                "net": 82.63,
                                "gross": 98.33,
                                "linked": false
                            }
                        ],
                        "categories":[
                            { 
                                "id":"648875017ed54637a41c8c1f972c239f",
                                "name":"Kategoriename"
                            }
                        ],
                        "configuratorSettings": [
                            { 
                                "productId": "25c8876fb7577cad78df7539737d25ce",
                                "optionId": "b224173313cb4f8da03578ef83702751" 
                            },
                            {   
                                "productId": "25c8876fb7577cad78df7539737d25ce",
                                "optionId": "0fcf784970ea448bac1f7db542df9b86" 
                            },
                            { 
                                "productId": "25c8876fb7577cad78df7539737d25ce",
                                "optionId": "0014aa7dc0b644b78cd4b39193f580b4" 
                            }
                        ],
                        "properties": [
                            { 
                                "groupId":"ca74efd59b5545f2b4e4f532c217b2ce",
                                "name": "6,0 m" 
                            },
                            { 
                                "groupId":"fa7f63d697d44684a5bb74ba5a73d3c7",
                                "name": "2,0 mm" 
                            },
                            { 
                                "groupId":"a431bc98fe0149c3bf3ececf629e9740",
                                "name": "Material" 
                            }
                        ],
                        "parentId": "17cf3bac8966cc4de52aa557f59e5fd3",
                        "options": [
                            { 
                                "id":"b224173313cb4f8da03578ef83702751",
                                "group": {
                                    "id":"ca74efd59b5545f2b4e4f532c217b2ce"}
                                },
                                { 
                                "id":"0fcf784970ea448bac1f7db542df9b86",
                                "group": {
                                    "id":"fa7f63d697d44684a5bb74ba5a73d3c7"}
                                },
                                { 
                                "id":"0014aa7dc0b644b78cd4b39193f580b4",
                                "group": {
                                    "id":"a431bc98fe0149c3bf3ececf629e9740"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "visibilities": [
                            {
                                "id": "25c8876fb7577cad78df7539737d25ce",
                                "salesChannelId": "840a0403b56240b6a11502af1d46521e",
                                "visibility": 30
                            }
                        ],
                        "media": [
                            { 
                                "media": { 
                                    "id": "fba6e74294488b554aa88f7dcf6f38f2", 
                                    "position": 0, 
                                    "mediaFolderId": "d8f460870e454c0bbca540614ca30029",
                                    "alt": "Bildname Kindelement", 
                                    "description": "Beschreibung Kindelement", 
                                    "title": "Bildtitel Kindelement" 
                                } 
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ] 
    } 
}
```

I'm searching in different boards and looking in the API Browser, Using swagger for the api and so on. No result. I need the main-product and the variants be visible in the frontend. At the moment all products with variants are invisible in the frontend.

Comment: Could you please format/pretty-print the json payload? currently it is really hard to understand

Comment: The `configuratorSettings` are not needed on the child products, you should omit it there, as it makes no sense, but i don't know if that causes your problem.

Comment: In the `configuratorSettings` of the parent you use an `optionId` `2ab9df7d2dd94ad38eb53cf7dcf16e56 ` which you don't use in the `options` of the child and in the `options` of the child you use an `id` `b224173313cb4f8da03578ef83702751 ` which is missing in the `configuratorSettings` of the parent. Try making these equal.

Comment: Thx. The different Id's are a copy and paste error. Sorry. At the moment I'm trying to split the requests. First I create the mainproduct, then upload the media. Second I create the variants and upload there media. Third I update the product for the relationship. I hope this will help for me for a better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Double check your Visibility & Categories. It could be them. Also, maybe you need to re-index after creation?

---

You have way too much stuff going on at the moment for us to help you out.
Try to split your calls into smaller chunks (for us). Also start with less data when creating a product. With every step check the frontend. Can you even create a simple product & display it on the frontend? Yes? Then try create the most basic child that inherits most of the visible parent.

For a child you do not need much data, e.g.

```json
{
    "write-product": {
        "entity": "product",
        "action": "upsert",
        "payload": [
            {
                "parentId": "",
                "options": [
                    {
                        "id": ""
                    }
                ],
                "price": [
                    {
                        "currencyId": "{{gen_salesChannel_currency_id}}",
                        "gross": 0.0,
                        "net": 0.0,
                        "linked": false
                    }
                ]
                "productNumber": "",
                "stock": 999
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Another tip is to use the network tab in the admin to see how it creates these relationships. Here is an image of how it looks like:
[image]

Comment: I got it, thx. I split the calls and the last step was to patch the product. There I had the problem. The last request is:
'
{
    "id": "aa4ccd7075a75e4ae497128c59989aab",
    "variantListingConfig": { 
        "displayParent": true
    },
    "configuratorSettings": [
        {
            "id": "5d032d664299cf32221b30abf7542458",
            "optionId": "fd7276b9f53e4bad80b78ebd75c2cd97"
        }
    ]
}
'
The id in the configuratorSettings is the variant id.

Comment: @ReneSchustek great! You may as well create a post with an answer & mark it as accepted. This helps viewers who unnecessarily come to this post to resolve it.